# Is Sencha Charts removed from ExtJS 7.0 Classic GPL?

Tags: npm, extjs, sencha-cmd

I successfully installed ExtJS 7.0 GPL through `npm` but it fails to include the chart component referenced in the app.json as below.

```
"requires": [
   "charts"
]
```

The error I get when I run `nmp start` is the following.

```
    i [ext]: ext-webpack-plugin v7.0.0, Ext JS v7.0.0 Commercial Edition, Sencha Cmd v7.0.0.40, webpack v4.39.3n/a
    i [ext]: Starting development build for extjs
    i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:1962/
    i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
    i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from ./
    i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
    i [ext]: Processing Build Descriptor : classic (development environment)
    i [ext]: [ERR] Cannot satisfy requirements for "charts"! [ERR]    The following versions cannot be satisfied: [ERR]       Monitor: charts (No matches!)
    i [ext]: [ERR] Cannot resolve package requirements
    i [ext]: [ERR]
    i [ext]: [ERR] The application was last modified by an older version of Sencha Cmd (7.2.0.84). [ERR] Installing a newer Sencha Cmd version may resolve the error described above. [ERR]
    ******************************************
    i [ext]: Cannot satisfy requirements for "charts"! [ERR]    The following versions cannot be satisfied: [ERR]       Monitor: charts (No matches!)
    ******************************************
```

The same error happens in clean install and upgrade.

Is this a license issue or I am missing something in the `app.json`?

Comment: Did you first try to solve the "last modified by an older version of Sencha Cmd" error?

Comment: Yes I did. I went upto Sencha Cmd (7.2.0.84), which was the latest.

Comment: No answer for this question? It seems like I am the only one trying to use ExtJS 7.0 GPL...

Answer (score 0):

Double check under the node_modules/@sencha directory to see if an ext-charts directory exists.

If not you'll need to install that module

```
npm install @sencha/ext-charts@7.0.0
```